# Generating a list of 1000 random numbers between 1 and 10 then counting amount of removed sevens

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a school project I am workin gon and I am really struggling to figure this one out..

The project is to generate a list of 1000 random numbers between 1 and 10 and then removing every instance of 7 in this list. But the tricky part is that we are supposed to count the amount of removed 7s and printing this to the console...

Any ideas?

This is not my code and is just something I am playing around with but this is what I got so far.

```
    <!-- Document Required Information -->
<!doctype html>
<!-- Language & Input Types -->
<html lang="no">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- utf-8 gjør at vi kan bruke æ, ø og å -->

<head>
    <title> Oppgave 3 Prøve 3D - 3F - Julian </title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function getRandomExcept(min, max, except) {
            except.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a - b;
            });
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1 - except.length)) + min;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < except.length; i++) {
                if (except[i] > random) {
                    break;
                }
                random++;
            }
            return random;
        }

        (function(min, max, except) {
            var iterations = 1000;
            var i;
            var random;
            var results = {};
            for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                random = getRandomExcept(min, max, except);
                results[random] = (results[random] || 0) + 1;
            }
            for (random in results) {
                console.log("Antall 7 Fjernet " + except.length + " Tall: " + random + ", Antall: " + results[random] + ", sjanse: " + results[random] * 100 / iterations + "%");
            }
        })(1, 10, [7]);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you A) tag a language and B) post what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @coglialoro This not really a homework question as the project is finished. But I am still wanting to figure out how this would work.

Comment: So, let's say we managed to generate 100 (or 1000, but 100 is simpler) random numbers (all between 1 & 10). Next, we remove all 7's from the list of 100 (or 1000) numbers. Now, we simply count how many numbers we have left - and let us assume we have 85 numbers. So, from 100 numbers we only have 85 numbers. Which means that we removed 15 numbers & since we removed all 7s - so the total number of 7's removed is 15. This seems too rudimentary. Surely I'm missing something here. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple solution:

```js
// Start with an empty array
let numbers = [];

// Do a for loop where you generate your 1000 numbers 
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  // Math.random() return a floating number from 0 to 1 (exclusive), if you multiply it by 10
  // you get a floating number between 0 and 10 (exclusive). Math.floor() cuts the decimal part
  // giving you an integer number between 0 and 9, so you add 1 to get a number between 1 and 10
  numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}

// You can use filter to remove the sevens
numbers = numbers.filter(el => el !== 7);

// Then you can just compare the length of the array
const removed = 1000 - numbers.length;

console.log(removed);
```